# How to show a tool tip in jquery for a dynamically created HTML table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a table dynamically by JQuery

```
function draw_top_five_table(data) {
        var json_array = data.json_array;
    /*Top five stat entities table*/
    var table_string = "<table class='common_data_grid top20' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' id='top_five_table'>"
                        + "<tr><td> </th><th>URL</th><th width='90'>Total Hits</th><th width='380'>Percentage of all Hits</th></tr>"

    for (var json_count = 0; json_count < json_array.length; json_count++)
    {
        var raw_tag = "<tr><td>" + (json_count+1) + "</td>"
            + "<td><a title=" + json_array[json_count].url_name + " href=/tophundredviewreport/?key="
            + json_array[json_count].url_id + ">"
            + json_array[json_count].url_name + "</a></td>"
            + "<td align='right'><div title='<div>Facebook Hits:" + json_array[json_count].facebook_count
            + "<br/> Twitter Hits:" + json_array[json_count].twitter_count
            + "<br/> Google+ Hits:" + json_array[json_count].buzz_count
            + "<br/> LinkedIn Hits:" + json_array[json_count].linkedin_count
            + "<br/> Digg Hits:" + json_array[json_count].digg_count
            + "<br/> Delicious Hits:" + json_array[json_count].delicious_count
            + "<br/> Reddit Hits:" + json_array[json_count].reddit_count + "</div>'>"
            + json_array[json_count].total_count + "</div></td>"
            + "<td><div title='<div>Facebook Hits:"
            + (json_array[json_count].facebook_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) + "%"
            + "<br/> Twitter Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].twitter_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) + "% "
            + "<br/> Google+ Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].buzz_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) + "%"
            + "<br/> LinkedIn Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].linkedin_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) +" %"
            + "<br/> Digg Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].digg_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) + "%"
            + "<br/> Delicious Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].delicious_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100)+" %"
            + "<br/> Reddit Hits:" + (json_array[json_count].reddit_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100 ).toFixed(2) + "%</div>'"
            + "class='progress'>" + (json_array[json_count].total_count/json_array[json_count].sum_total*100).toFixed(2) + "</div></td>"
            + "</tr>"
        table_string = table_string + raw_tag;
    }
    var end_tag = "</table>";
    table_string = table_string + end_tag + "<br>";

    $("#top_five_stat").html(table_string)
    $('.common_data_grid td .progress').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $percentage = $this.text();
        $this.empty();
        $this.wrapInner('<div class="progress_inner" />');
        $('.progress_inner',$this).text(' ');
        $width = ((200/100)*$percentage);
        $this.animate({width:$width},3000);
        $this.parent().append('<span class="number">'+ $percentage +'%</span>');
    });
    }
```

but there s a problem with the tool tip which shows the break down in column two and three . It is not rendering properly and it is showing the HTML elements once i ran the mouse over it. Can any one help me  to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the native tooltip showed by the browser with the value of the `title` attribute ?
Unfortunately, you cannot put HTML in there, it will be considered as pure text.

You have to use a tooltip plugin to have formatted/complex tooltip content. There are plenty of them based on jquery:

- [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)
- [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)
- [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)
- [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)
- [Coda Popup Bubbles](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/)

By the way, I've noticed a problem in your code, you have to enclose the `href` value between double-quotes:

```
... + " href=/tophundredviewreport/?key=" + (id) + ">" + ...

should be

... + " href=\"/tophundredviewreport/?key=" + id + "\">" + ...
```

To lighten your code a little bit, and because it would be a bit more efficient, I would extract the current item from the array in the loop, like this:

```
for (var json_count = 0; json_count < json_array.length; json_count++)
{
    var item = json_array[json_count];

    // then you can use item.twitter_count, item.url_name ...
}
```